# How to pass corresponding index of an array to onPress

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

Im trying to make a button which when clicked adds an item to cart, but the problem i have is, I want to pass the index of that particular item to the Get Ticket button `onPress={() => handleAddToCart(getListingsApi.data[0].slug)}`. Instead of zero, it should be the particular index of the data dynamically.

```
    function GetTicket(props) {
    ....
    const handleAddToCart = (slug) => {
        setLoading(true);
        // addToCart()
        client
          .post(endpoint, { slug })
          .then((res) => {
            console.log(res.data);
            console.log("Q2");
            // this.props.refreshCart();
            setLoading(false);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            setError(err);
            setLoading(false);
          });
      };
    return (
      <View>
      {getListingsApi.data && (
        
        <TouchableOpacity>
          <AppButton
            title="Get Ticket"
            onPress={() => handleAddToCart(getListingsApi.data[0].slug)}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Which index do you want to pass to the handleAddToCart function, the index you'll get from the API?

Answer (score 0):

you are not loading the data in a list or FlatList, you only displaying one item from the data, Then how can you get the index dynamically?, from your code you have only one app button .